# is RPMB Fuse Set a factory state?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, samsung-knox, warranty

[image: from Download mode screen of my Android device]

I bought a Galaxy Tab S6 and I'm going to verify if it is really brand-new.

I personally haven't alter the device and the above picture is from this device's Download mode screen immediately after my purchase. It reads:

- RPMB fuse Set
- KG STATUS : PRENORMAL

I have no idea whether `RPMB fuse Set` is a factory state. Is it?

Concerning `KG STATUS` being `PRENORMAL`, I don't think this as a factory state (it seems the seller has already tried to flash an unofficial ROM or perhaps tried to flash back the official ROM from Android 10 to 9)

Do you see any clue that could be used to prove that this device is not in factory state and not brand-new?

Comment: At this point, many questions into this topic already noted, it might be the only way to satisfy your need for privacy may be your design and building of a device to your personal specs. Marginal paranoia is to be expected, since the consuming of products sold by others makes it necessary. Perhaps the seller doesn't make you comfortable. Avoid buying from him then.

Comment: I really couldn't find any post to answer this question.

Comment: This is a question that many people have but not answered clearly according to my search

Comment: People have this question that which one is factory state: ```RPMB Fuse Set``` or ```RPMB Fuse Blown```? (I've asked this in my other question as well)

Comment: consider mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

**What i know:**

*RPMB fuse* - should be set, not blown

*Current binary* - is samsung official which is to be expected (if there was something else it would say something like "Custom (0xE03)" instead)

*FRP lock* - is off, which should be that way, it's factory reset protection which means that FRP protected device even after factory reset will require you to log into your google account

*OEM lock* - is on, this means the bootloader is locked (should be locked)

*Warranty void* - is 0, this is knox counter and if you try to flash anything on a new device it will trip and always show 0x1 in download mode. Right now afaik there's no way to set it back to 0x0

**What i don't know:**

RPMB provisioned - RPMB is replay protected memory block (or something like that) and provisioned seems to be its normal state, but from what i could find it relates more to memory integrity than to flashing, so it probably will not change after you install something

KG status prenormal - KG is knox guard, and on my new device i think it was prenormal already, checked on other new device - it was "completed". I don't know what exactly does this status mean, only thing i know is that with prenormal status you can't flash custom roms/recovery/etc

Qualcomm secureboot and secure download - were always enabled for me, and i honestly have no idea if you can even change that

SPU[VALID]:5 - don't know what it is, quick googling gave zero results, i guess it's good that it is valid

**Conclusion:**

I'd say your device is brand new and with stock everything, but i don't know if there are any clues of it being refurbished, so no hints on that